# How to change the domain (i.e. polynomial ring) using sympy in Pytho?

Tags: python, methods, sympy, polynomials, ring

I'm in the middle of a big (and frankly quite hard) project so while this is my first interrogation, it probably won't be the last. Also : english is not my first langage so 'Sorry for bad english' and I'm writing this on my phone so 'Sorry for bad formating'.
Ok so : I'm trying to implement the General Number Field Sieve in Python, and I'm, at least for now, heavily relying on sympy.

Here is a peice of code where I'm struggling. In the code below, `gpc(N,m)` is a float list.

```
From sympy import Poly
From sympy.abc import x

g = Poly(gpc(N,m), x) [*]
```

However, when I do that, I get a polynomial over the domain RR and I would very much like to switch this to another domain D (where D will end up being `ZZ['x']` but I would like this function to be general)

I'm aware of the fact that I can slightly modify  [*] in

```
g = Poly(gpc(N,m), x, domain = D)
```

to get what I want. However, this wouldn't be enough. Somewhere else in my code, I need to be able to change the domain of an already constructed polynomial, and this solution wouldn't help.

When I lookep it up, I found the `change_ring` method so I tried this :

```
f = g.change_ring(D)
```

However, upon execution, I get the error message :

```
'Poly' object has no attribute 'change_ring'
```

So I guess that this function don't exist.
Does anyone knows how to change the domain of a polynomial ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like creating a new `Poly` instance is the best approach; there are a few class methods that could help (take a look at the `Poly.from_*` class methods)

For example:

```
from sympy import Poly
from sympy.abc import x, a

g = Poly(x**3 + a*x*2 - 5*x + 6, x)
print(g)  # Poly(x**3 + (2*a - 5)*x + 6, x, domain='ZZ[a]')

f = Poly.from_poly(g, *g.gens, domain='ZZ[a, b]')
print(f)  # Poly(x**3 + (2*a - 5)*x + 6, x, domain='ZZ[a,b]')
```

I also wonder if rationalizing your floats at some point might help - see e.g. `nsimplify`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked ! Also, I think there is no need to rationalize my floats because from this point on I only work with sympy polynomials (over ```ZZ['x']```)